# Enumerator overhead vs indexers in strings performance

Tags: c#, linq

I was charged with speeding up a text processing/normalization section of our code, and there were multiple sections that had multiple, configurable lists of "if you see this, replace with that", and they were implemented with big stacks of regexes.  That looked like a good place to start - and it was.

I implemented a simple Trie loaded with the configuration entries and then had a

```
Match (string raw, int idx = 0)
```

function that skimmed the raw input, looking through the Trie for matches.

My first draft of the match function used a for loop and an indexer (i.e.

```
TrieNode node = Root;
for (; idx < raw.Length; idx++)
{
    TrieNode next;
    if (node.TryGetValue(raw[idx], out next))
    ...
```

In it and it was several orders of magnitude faster than a pile of regexes.

I wanted to clean up and generalize the Trie, maybe make it configurable for either chars or words as tokens, and after all the generisizing I replaced the above with

```
foreach (var c in idx > 0 ? raw.Skip(idx) : raw)
{
    ...
```

and was surprised to see just how much overhead the change in iteration caused.  I expected there to be some overhead but the foreach method was about 100x slower (4300 ms per run of 100 articles vs 40 ms with for loop) - just that change alone.

I've seen lots of articles from various time periods saying "of course Linq and enumerators suck!" to "always use foreach because the performance is close enough and foreach is cooler".

None of the oflow articles I found were very current so I thought I'd drop this note in a bottle.

I get the enumerator allocation is going to add a little overhead and Skip() is never going to be as fast as jumping right ahead with an indexer, but it was a pretty stark contrast.

I did find a debate about whether String should implement IReadOnlyList or not, which seems like it could have been the best of both worlds but that doesn't exist.

Is anyone else surprised that has that amount of overhead?

Comment: I am not sure that your `foreach` code shows everything comparable to your `for` code (what is `idx` in the `foreach`?) but `Skip` is not a very efficient way to offset the `foreach` , `Span` would be better - in general, `for` > `foreach` > LINQ for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Span...  I haven't used that before.

The idx is the same idx as the other for example - the index into the raw input you're starting to look at.  It would be paragraphs of text, where idx jumps ahead at word boundaries before looking again for a Trie match

Answer (score 3):

I'm not surprised that `Skip` is orders of magnitude slower since it will be O(n) (essentially incrementing an integer until you get to `idx`) versus O(1) for the direct indexer.

I would not generalize this to "Linq sucks - use `foreach`". You could implement functionally the same code as `Skip` in your `foreach` and get roughly the same results. The problem is not that you're using Linq - the problem is that you're using `Skip` on a collection that supports direct access.

If you want to generalize it to use either chars or words as tokens, it may be simplest to convert `raw` to a `List<T>` and support either a list of chars or a list of strings - with what you have, there should not be a significant performance difference between the two.

Comment: The "linq sucks" was my rather cavalier interpretation of some old Oflow articles I could find on the overhead of various types of iteration into strings.

I started looking into it because I was trying to generalize "skim a string" to "skim a T" and ran the program again with T as string.  That's when I noticed the huge difference and boiled it down to that foreach.

I was a little worried about the allocation overhead of converting / copying to a List<T> (string.ToCharArray() by the current example).

Comment: Understood. `string.ToCharArray() ` should be pretty cheap as it's just copying an internal array - so you only have to do it once. That said, there's nothing wrong with having two very similar methods - one for string and one for a generic `List<T>` if you want to optimize the string access. My guess is that your performance gain of not using regex is the biggest win here.

Comment: The other thread I found on this journey was asking "Why doesn't string implement IReadOnlyList<char>?"  I kinda liked the idea though some purists objected that it violates Liskov (but a whole lot of things in the framework do).

Comment: Motivated by the Span<> suggestion above, I implemented a little wrapper class around string to implement IList<> access to it.  We're not using the latest .net core, so Span<> wasn't an option.

So offering IEnurmerable<> and IList<> versions of the Match method (the latter using for and an indexer) and passing in the IList<> wrapper on a string got the performance right back where it was.

I know a wrapper class that returns true for IsReadOnly and throws NotImplemented for any of the modifying methods isn't elegant but it did the job.